# Inserting into the middle of an ordered linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

My code is stuck in a infinite loop when I try and add to a middle position of my ordered linked list.  It works if I add to a null list or if I need to add to the end. I assume I'm stuck in a circular loop somewhere.

```
while(current != NULL){
    if(new->Id < current->Id){
            //insert
        printf("%s","here bro");
        new->next = current;
        prev->next = new;
        break;
    }

    if(current->next == NULL){
        printf("%s\n","getting here\n");
        current->next = new;
        break;
    }

    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Any steps in the right direction would be great.

Comment: First thing that strikes the mind like a firebolt ... never, ever use the word new unless you are allocating a new object in C++.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your problem may or may not be in this bit of code that you have shown.

Comment: Missing is code that initializes prev. Also missing is code that sets new->next = NULL if it's added to the end of the list.

Comment: JVene, I see no problem with using `new` as an identifier in C. Doing this is even beneficial because it guards against accidental usage of a C++ compiler. C code (with the exception of header files or generated code specifically designed to be C++-compatible) should never be compiled using a C++ compiler.